# Netbeans code formatting comment blocks

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, docblock, joomla-coding-standards

I use Netbeans for Joomla extensions development, I want to stick to Joomla coding standards but I have a problem with the first phpdoc comment block.

I know this is an stupid question but it's driving me crazy.

I can't configure first blank line after first comment when using Netbeans code auto formatting, when hitting SHIFT + CMD + F I get this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Package
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) Owner. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU GPLv2 <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die();
```

I haven't found the way I can achieve this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Package
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) Owner. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU GPLv2 <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die();
```

Note the blank line between the comment block and the first php line

Does anyone else use this feature of Netbeans to format code PSR-2 style? Did you solved this Netbeans issue?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Joomla itself, but with Netbeans. I suggest you try asking on Stackoverflow

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712285/editing-the-netbeans-source-formatting-standard

Answer (score 2):

Even though, I use Eclipse for development. This link may guide you to look for similar preferences in Netbeans to configure the tool.

https://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_Eclipse_IDE_for_PHP_development/Linux#Configuring_the_editors